# Cons of using a star schema in a columnar database

Tags: database-design, olap, redshift, memory-optimized-tables, star-schema

My organisation is implementing a new data warehouse using a columnar data store (Redshift) and the performance is currently abysmal.  There are many causes for this but I think the key reason is because of the way we have our data structured, we're implementing a classic star schema design, which surely is optimal for a traditional RDBMS (OLTP) and not necessarily for OLAP?

I'm looking for someone with experience on this to briefly explain the pros and cons of structuring large quantities of data in a star schema on amazon redshift.

I'm obviously no expert, but I'm looking for some advice and guidance on this.

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up three orthogonal concepts: data model (star schema), workload characteristics (OLTP vs. OLAP), and physical data organisation (columnar).

Your data model has no bearing on whether column-organised tables are appropriate for you; however, data organisation must reflect the nature of your workload (i.e. queries). For example, `SELECT * FROM...` cannot possibly perform well in a columnar database.

Answer (score 1):

Mustaccio's answer is good.  In addition,  every star schema  I have ever seen was implemented on top of a relational DBMS, often Oracle.  Also, the data in it was downstream from some kind or operational database, also on a relational DBMS.  The operational database was mostly normalized and used for OLTP.

I have **never** seen a star schema used for OLTP.  I can't imagine anybody ever doing that.  It's not what star schema is for.